# PHP Memory Error(No File Name specified)

Tags: php

I am getting php error like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 7077994 bytes) in **Unknown on line 0**, referer:REFERER

I have checked my code there is no infinite loop or code which will take such high memory.

**I concern is why it is not showing the error line where it has happened.What is the meaning of Unknown in this case..**

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Trying to allocate 7mb in 1 pass is quite a lot. Is it during an upload? You only have 32mb set for `memory_limit`, which may be too low. I tend to get the `Unknown on line 0` error when trying to do something during deconstruction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) installed?
I would try to increment `memory_limit` and profile your script with xdebug. It produces a human-readable text file. So you can read where and how much memory is used.

Comment: @Shashwhat - Then replicate your live environment on a test server and install xdebug on that. Either way xdebug will give you a decent idea as to where your memory problems are coming from.

Comment: Yeah..My main question is in case of memory errors in shows the line number where is occurred .In which cases in shows Unknown?

Answer (score 0):

memory_limit = 128M

increase it in your php.ini file.

Or visit the link below

[memory limit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP)